# MySQL: symbols in queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I recently noticed that there are several strange symbols used in MySQL queries that I haven't seen before. I never used them but I'm trying to understand their meaning. I haven't found any information regarding this since I don't know how they're called.

Let's say, I have this table:

```
id  | city | population 
250 | Carlisle | 75305
```

1. What is this `|`? What is the output of it?

`UPDATE cities SET population = population | 5 WHERE id = 250`

2. Even more complex situation.

`UPDATE cities SET population = population & ~2 | 6 WHERE id = 250`

3. Query with "where" clause. What WHERE clause is this? What rows would be selected?

`SELECT * FROM cities WHERE population & 2 > 0`

4. Multiple values in INSERT INTO query through PHP. What are those %s and %u values? How to know whether %s or %u should be put in query? Why should I use this instead of simple query with values put directly in VALUES area?

`sprintf("INSERT INTO cities (id, city, population) VALUES ('%s', '%u', '%s')", $id, $city, $population);`

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strange symbols you mention are bitwise operators, you may want to take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html) for more information.

The %s, %u, etc are PHP format specifications. For full information look [here](http://php.net/sprintf).

You can certainly create a string in PHP with the values directly into a VALUES clause. The format specifiers can help remind what types the corresponding database columns are.

Your example can also be written as :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cities (id, city, population) VALUES ('$id', '$city', '$population')";
```

Comment: Thank you for information. Now I know what are they and how they're called.

Answer (score 2):

`UPDATE cities SET population = population | 5 WHERE id = 250`

This query is going to do bitwise OR on each existing `population` with `101` (binary of 5) and set the result back to population.

`UPDATE cities SET population = population & ~2 | 6 WHERE id = 250`

Similar as first one just operator precedence needs to be taken care of. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

sprintf is used to create a string with certain fixed part and certain variable part. And %s, %u specifies the formats of the variable parts.
After the initial string each comma separated variable represents value to be placed at format specifier in order of position.

http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: Thank you for an example. I understand more of this now.